# WS library and Content-Encoding/Accept-Encoding headers

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, spray

I'm not sure if the issue here is with Spray or with Play Framework.

I have an API server running on Spray which I'm making requests to from a Play app using the WS lib. On my Spray route, I am using the `compressResponseIfRequested` directive. When I make requests using curl, I can see that the content-length is shorter than it is without compression and that the content-encoding header is coming back as "gzip".

However, when I make the request using the WS lib from Play, the content-length is the length of the uncompressed response and, indeed, there is no content-encoding header present. This is the case, even though I am including an `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header in the request. I can even see when I log the response headers inside of my Spray app as it's completing the request that the Content-Encoding: gzip header is present.

What am I doing wrong here? Any suggestions for debugging this further would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might seem like a slightly crazy suggestion, but consider trying with an alternative HTTP client library, specifically, I'd recommend [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

OkHttp is an excellent modern Java-based async-HTTP library which supports lots of great stuff like SNI, Disk-Based caching on ETags, etc. It's been adopted as the underlying HTTP client library on the latest versions of Android. I've used it several times as a problem-fixing stand-in for the Play-WS library (which is [Netty](http://netty.io/)-based, like Dispatch). It's easy to wrap OkHttp for Scala use, see the files changed in this pull request:

https://github.com/guardian/prout/pull/9/files#diff-1

Definitely worth giving OkHttp a try!